# Is it possible to construct the joint distribution of multinomial distribution?

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution

Is it possible to construct the joint probability density of multinomial distribution?

May you assume two multinomial distributions are independent and multiply their distributions to obtain the joint distribution?

Comment: You can assume independence if it is true

Comment: Once you define what do you understand by "the joint probability density of multinomial distribution" we might try to answer that. Let me help you - starting with two variables: let $(X,Y)$ be a pair of jointly distributed random variables. We'll say that they are "jointly multinomial" if _[.... please complete this]_.